# AWT string width depends on DPI

Tags: java, fonts, awt

We are developing an application for printing. The same text is rendered using AWT in two modes with different resolutions - screen (small DPI) and printing (300 DPI).

The problem is that text layout depends on DPI. And this dependency is non-linear. There are examples:

[image]
Width: 200 px, font size: 10 pt

[image]
Width: 400 px, font size: 20 pt

[image]
Width: 600 px, font size: 30 pt

The rectangle width and font size are increasing proportionally from the first to the third image. But on the first image we have only "lazy", on the second we have "lazy do", and on the third only "lazy d".

Is there any way to constrain text layout while increasing total image size in pixels?

Comment: Is there a reason you are constrained to using AWT? Maybe it would be easier to use some other library. An SVG renderer might be nice.

Comment: Interesting question.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Christopher Martin, could you please advise some good library for text rendering? We use AWT because it is easy to use single Graphics2D context to render images and text together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
```

Comment: Ten years old, but saved my day today!

Answer (score 0):

An SVG renderer might suit you better, because you'd be able to build a single vector image and render it at arbitrary pixel density.

[Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) might work, although I've never used it.

Comment: What is SVG renderer? Is that a Java library?

Comment: SVG is a format for vector graphics. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics - Batik is a Java library for dealing with SVG files.

Comment: The problem with SVG is that I don't see how to wrap text in lines.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought the answer to that would be simple, but it doesn't seem so. You might want to open another Stack Overflow question for that.